# Deep attribute pulling with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on an ember.js app using ember-data and fixtures.  I have the following:

```
App.DevicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
   model: function() {
      return App.Device.find();
   }
});

App.DevicesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   tableData: function() {
      return this.map(function (p) {
         return (["<a href='/#/device/"+p.get("id")+"'>D"+p.get("id")+"</a>",p.get("fn"),'N'+p.get('network.id'),"?",p.get("throughput"),p.get("throughput"),p.get("users.length")]);
      });
   }.property('@each.fn', '@each.users.length', '@each.network.id')
});
```

This works fine, but when I switch the `@each.network.id` and `p.get('network.id')` in the above to be `fn` instead (a property that exists on `App.Network`), then it fails to get any data.

I have `belongsTo('App.Network')` set up on `App.Device` and `hasMany('App.Device')` on `App.Network`.

Also, the following works fine:

```
App.Device.find(1).then(function(d) {alert(d.get('fn'));});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Obviously I need to set up the data dependency for the property in some other way, but what was is that?